# Python. Updating values to existing columns excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, web-scraping

I have an excel file like this.
[image: Excel Sheet]

I am scraping new data from the web for D and E column using this code.

```
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

urls =['https://www.linkedin.com/in/felipe-fs',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/lucascacao',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/silvia-florido-107a2355',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/alesillva',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/marcellogpassos',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/ana-luiza-fidelis-de-sousa',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/thiagoanjos',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/eduardoneves',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/gabriel-de-santana-weizenmann-73aab7116',
'https://www.linkedin.com/in/felipebluiz']


header_added = False
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
driver.maximize_window()
for url in urls:
    driver.get(url)

    try:
        n = False
        company = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@class="pv-top-card--experience-list"]')
        if not n:
            res = company.text
            n = True

        html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        for i in range(2):
            html.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
            time.sleep(3)
        experience = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h4')
        duration = experience[0].text
        with open('test.xlxs', 'a', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
            w = csv.writer(f)
            w.writerow(['', '', '', res, duration])
    except:
        print("User has an older job")
```

**The data in D and E is only for 4-5 rows, so this can be overwritten**. How do I update these columns with the new scraped data? I saw many answers but not sure how to make a data frame of scraped data.I need to read the url from the same file and scrape data and add it to the existing columns. The url list in the code is just a test.

**EDIT**:- I looked around and decided it's more convenient to simply convert the xlsx to a csv. So I installed xlrd ver 1.2 and did that.

Answer (score 2):

**Input**: String url was use and newdata of D and C column.

**Output**: update row.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook,Workbook
       
 def update(url,dataDcol,dataEcol):
    try:
        #get date
        wk = load_workbook('oldfile.xlsx')
        wh = wk.active
        for row in wh['C']:
            if row.value == url:
                    wh['D{}'.format(row.row)] = dataDcol
                    wh['E{}'.format(row.row)] = dataEcol
            break
        wk.save('oldfile.xlsx')
        wk.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('error :' + str(e))
```

Comment: I think Excel is an overall pain in python. I converted the excel to a csv. I think I will work with a csv. Thanks for your answer.